# after upgraded npm got error when run npm

Tags: node.js, npm

i just run "npm install -g npm" in my centos 6.5, after that i run npm -v, there is a error message

```
# npm uninstall npm -g

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npm-registry-client'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:9:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

how can i solve the problem? or should i remove npm completely and reinstall again?

Comment: Try this 

    `npm install npm-registry-client`

Comment: there will a folder named as `node-modules` in your working directory. Just remove that and tries to run command again

Comment: what is the node-modules location, i didn't find that

Comment: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm i just found here

Answer (score 0):

Remove and reinstall sound good.

To remove you can see in this official site of NPM those actions:

```sh
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

and if this isn't working you can try from source

```sh
sudo make uninstall
```

Here are the full details:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html